# Tasks in C# are executing sequentially and not concurrently

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, static-variables

For purely experimental reasons, I am trying to write a psuedo-random number generator using `Task`s in C#

I have 2 tasks, and 2 static variables `glo_a` and `glo_count`. `glo_a` is supposed to hold the final result (a 7-bit random binary integer).

```
public static int glo_a = 0, glo_count = 6;

Private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Task task = new Task(() => this.display(1));
  Task task2 = new Task(() => this.display(0));

  task.Start();
  task2.Start();

  Task.WaitAll();
  textBox1.AppendText("\n" + glo_a);
}

public void display(int j)
{
  for (; glo_count >= 0; glo_count--)
  {  
    glo_a += j * (int)Math.Pow(10,glo_count);
  }
}

private void refreshbutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  /* reset the original values*/  
  glo_a = 0;
  glo_count = 6;
  textBox1.Text = "";  
}
```

The problem I'm having is that `task` executes first and completes before `task2` begins every single time.

Comment: There's so little for the tasks to do, it's hardly surprising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the tasks have very little to do chances are they'll end up running one after the other, and since you started task1 first, that's likely to get run first.

As other answers have said, just use the `Random` class.

Answer (score 2):

Can I ask why you're not just generating "bits" using this:

```
Random r = new Random();
r.Next(2);
```

or better yet:

```
Random r = new Random();
byte[] randomBytes = new byte[7];
r.NextBytes(randomBytes);
```

In any case, assuming you have a weird requirement to do what you're doing, are you sure they're running sequentially?

I would say it's more likely that the first Task is ending before the second Task has a chance to start.

In any case, this would be the same thing, but you could try:

```
Task.WaitAll(
    new Task( () => this.display(1) ),
    new Task( () => this.display(0) )
);
```

If you're desperate to use what you have, you could do a Random generation to decide which Task starts first:

```
Random r = new Random();

Task task = new Task(() => this.display(1));
Task task2 = new Task(() => this.display(0));
Task[] tasks = new [] { task, task2 };

/* Only supports 2 tasks */
int firstTask = r.Next(2); 

tasks[firstTask].Start();
tasks[firstTask ^ 1].Start();

Task.WaitAll();
```

Comment: This was just a learning thing. Basically the aim wasnt to generate random nos. I wanted to learn the functioning of the TPL. But the TPL is scheduling the tasks to the sequential execution because of the shared static variables (i guess). Is there any way of executing them simltaneously?  p.s.(i have an i5 processor, so uniprocessing isnt the issue ;) )

Comment: I would say it's not sequential execution, it's the fact the first Task is too small and is being processed too fast, or at least always before the 2nd task. Just because they are asynchronous (i.e. running at the same time) doesn't mean they have necessarily started in an uncertain order. If we both run on a track at the same time, but you start first, you could end first every time even though we were both running at the same time. I've put an update in on how you could switch which Task starts first but obviously that defeats the purpose.

Comment: umm... thanks. but as i said, my aim wasnt random num generation... i wanted to learn how tpl works... but i think u r right my 1st task ends before the 2nd begins... and i think sleep will solve it :)

Comment: thanks again...i think i got what to do ... the tasks were too short... i solved it